Steam doesn't load in Kubuntu after the first try
I downloaded Steam, and the first time it worked and opened. Now after restarting it doesn't open, but keeps trying to open and instantly disappearing. How to fix it?

If you start a terminal (ctrl+alt+t) and type steam, please cut and paste the error messages into your original posting.

Please add details which release of Ubuntu you are using and which Steam version you installed.
